# CSV File Generation - Danish Language not supported?

Tags: php, csv

Hi Friends now I am Generating a CSV File using

```
file_put_contents('test.csv',  $csv_output);
```

Through this i generate csv file and store it.When i saw the generated CSV file Danish language is not supported.In the place of Danish Language some other symbols are Shown.

I need a solution friends?

Comment: what language is that and why isn't it in the tags?

Comment: Danish language is not supporting.

Comment: I meant what programming language is that snippet.

Comment: well I imagine there's no conversion taking place and your file coding clashes with the table coding system.  All a very vague guess without having seen the details.

Comment: If you can afford the extra space overhead try UTF-8 both as file coding system as well as the table/column coding system.

Comment: i want to know how i can include UTF-8 inside this function...File_put_contents

Comment: you have to convert it beforehand, or maybe use some PHP `iconv` binding (I'm not a PHP expert, but I imagine there is such a thing)

Comment: Got it ...Here is the answer                                                                 file_put_contents($myFile, utf8_encode($myContent));

Comment: Thank You very much hroptatyr..May Jesus Bless You Abundantly

Comment: Nice one, put it as proper answer and mark this question as close then.

Comment: Oh no file_put_contents($myFile, utf8_encode($myContent)); it is not working

Comment: as i said, make sure mysql sends data that `utf8_encode()` can actually process

Answer (score 1):

Answer (as sorted out in the comments) is to have the table coding system set to UTF-8 and then use

```
file_put_contents($myFile, utf8_encode($myContent))
```

or, to let mysql do the encoding bit:

```
file_put_contents($myFile, $myContent);
```

when `myContent` comes from a `SELECT CONVERT(content USING utf8);`